# Does POI support enable the Track changes API?

Tags: java, apache-poi

As title description, I want to check the track change that modified by POI.
I tried to enable the function manually, but there's not any mark in modified word.

Comment: Apache POI has some, but limited Tracked Changes support. Expect to have to write a bit of code, and fix some bugs, if you want to use it. Tracked changes isn't magic though, you'll need to update the change info with POI at the same time as you modify the document!

Answer (score 0):

Before performing write operation, none changes will reflect on the real document. If you have made any change then to see that change you need to perform write operation.